# Correct structure for laravel app with 2 APIs providing data

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-6.2

I have a laravel application thT fetches API data from 2 different providers, they are different but will have similar data albeit in a different structure.

I’m trying to figure out how I can best make this as easy to maintain as possible in laravel.

Let’s say the data they send me are orders (order1Api, order2Api) with products but in a different structure.

I want to fetch them and convert them in a class that have a similar structure.

So I would need 2 classes to handle fetching the order dat for the seperate  APIs and the. I need 1 Model to make the data uniform?

I’m still learning laravel so am not sure if the APIs should be a service or facade Where could I best place the order so that I’m able to fetch data from them in different controllers if needed?

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is broad and subjective, I will take a stab at it.

If it were me, I would make a "service" class called something like `Orders` which is what your application interacts with. Inside of it, it handles the logic of determining which API to call and the *normalization* of data. It wouldn't do the individual service specific logic, it would proxy that out.

```php
// You might call something like this in your controller
$orders = Orders::all();
```

And inside that orders class:

```php
class Orders {

    function __construct() {
        $this->serviceHandlers = [
            new service1(),
            new service2(),
        ];
    }

    function all() {

        // Final output array
        $orders = [];

        foreach ($this->serviceHandlers as $handler) {

            // Get orders from specific service
            $results = $handler->getOrders();

            // Normalize data and add them to the orders
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $orders[] = $handler->normalize($result);
            }
        }

        return $orders;
    }
}
```

Then each handler class should have an abstract that forces them to implement a `getOrders()` and `normalize()` methods.

It would be best to make this service dynamically load the service API classes based on a config file so that you don't have them hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks I’m guessing this doc fits your description: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container